# Prevent password change prompt when switching users with su as root

Tags: password, pam, su

I am working with an Ubuntu system (22.04) and I have set a user's password to expire using the chage command by executing `chage user1 -d 0`. This prompts the user to change their password upon the next login, which is the desired behavior.

However, when I switch to user1 from root using the `su - user1` command, it also prompts for a password change, which is not desired.

Interestingly, on a CentOS system, executing su - user1 as root does not prompt for a password change after running `chage user1 -d 0`. I would like to replicate this behavior on my Ubuntu system.

I suspect this might be related to PAM configurations in the `/etc/pam.d` directory, but I am not sure what modifications are needed to achieve this behavior.

I would like to know how to configure my Ubuntu system so that when I run `su - user1` as `root`, it does not ask for a password change, even after I've run `chage user1 -d 0`. Any guidance on the specific PAM configurations or other settings that need to be adjusted would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Could you perhaps use `sudo -iu user1` instead?

Comment: Thanks, but not an option for me.

Comment: Simply do `sudo passwd user1` to change the password. Read `man sudo sudoers passwd`. `sudo -u user1 bash` would get you a `user1` shell.

Comment: I *suspect* the relevant line is `account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]        pam_unix.so` in  the /etc/pam.d/common-account file (included from /etc/pam.d/su). See the somewhat related [Root account locked/suspended?](https://superuser.com/a/607059)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Adding the following line -

```
account     sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so uid = 0 use_uid quiet
```

to `/etc/pam.d/su`